# Android populate the same custom listview layout with 2 different ArrayLists

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I'm new to android and I need help. I couldn't find a link that explains me what I'm going to ask, that's why I'm asking here.

I have a listview with one layout.

My customLayout have some textviews and images, all that I get from  2 jsonArrays inside one json object.

TEXT1 TEXT2 IMAGE1

I want to populate this layout from 2 different Array Lists.

I get this array lists from 2 jsonArrays on my webservice.

My class is a simple one, like this:

```
public class Example{

private String text;
private String text2;
private String imageLink;

Constructor...
Getter and Setter...
}
```

**I can put the values of ArrayList1 inside the customLayout but not the values of ArrayList2.**

Like this:

```
public class CustomListAdapterStreams extends ArrayAdapter<StreamsData> {


   ArrayList<MyClass> ArrayList;
    ArrayList<MyClass> ArrayList2;
    Context context;
    int resource;


    public CustomListAdapterStreams(Context context,  int resource,  ArrayList<MyClass> ArrayList, ArrayList<MyClass> ArrayList2;) {

        super(context, resource, ArrayList);
        this.ArrayList= ArrayList;
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.ArrayList2= ArrayList2;
    }

@Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_list_adapter, null);
            }

            MyClass myclass= ArrayList.get(position);
    String getUsername = myclass.getUsername();
    String quality = myclass.getQuality();

    TextView txtUsername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txtUsername.setText(getUsername);

    and so on
```

So I need to understand how to put in the same custom layout, in the same views, dinamically, different values. Like when Array List 1 has nothing left, populate the rest of the list with the values of Array List 2.

**EDIT:**

Answers saying I should put both json arrays in the same arraylist.

By a rookir mistake I thought that I shouldn't mix up two JSONArrays, into the same ArrayList but that is what solved my problems.

Thank you Wizard, I know it was a stupid question. Rookie mistake here.

Comment: Why can you not just combine the data in the lists after you've received them from the server?

Comment: you can merge the two arraylist in a single arraylist and use it for your custom listview

Comment: Exactly, Make one arrayList

Comment: they are from 2 different json arrays. CanI put both in the same ArrayList?

Comment: So what? Put items of `arrayList2` into `arrayList1`. Do you want me to show how you do that?

Comment: If both jsonarray have same fields you can surely merge the arraylist

Comment: Sorry, I should then do like int the EDIT part of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your two `arrayList` have same `Pojo`..

What you can do is Merge two `arrayList` and keep data in one `arrayList` before setting an adapter;

Here is how you can do that -

`arraList1.addAll(arraList2)`

Comment: Thank you Sr. I know it was a stupid question but I got confused about putting 2 jsonArrays with different names but same content inside one ArrayList. I thought I shouldn't do that for a reason but that was a rookie mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: That is what StackOverFlow for ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would join the two arrays.

```
for (Example item: arrayList2)
{
    arrayList1.add(item)
}
```

If you need to show different data for each array item, at the time of joining I would put a property to differentiate, type:

```
for (Example item: arrayList2)
{
   item.setIsArrayList2(true)
    arrayList1.add(item)
}
```

And it would apply to the Adapter where you could show the two and so on.

One tip: Use **optString** instead of **getString** to not get a JSONException in case it comes null

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although Wizard answered pretty well your answer is equivalent and helpful. I appreciate.